# Logging in Behave BDD framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, bdd, python-behave

I'm new with BDD in Python and I'm trying to create a framework. As per the documentation, I've created the environment.py file and in that there is a method:

```
def before_all(context):
    context.config.setup_logging(configfile="test.ini", filename="AppLog.log")
```

But I'm not sure what I need to add in my steps (step methods) so that my AppLog.log file will have the logs. Do I need to initialize a logger in my steps file? If yes, how this setup_logging will be used there?

If a sample code can be provided then it will be really helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Sunil

Answer (score 5):

In order to write the logs from within your steps into the file, you might try running behave by giving the parameter `no-logcapture`, the default behaviour of behave is to show log records only when a test fails.

From within your code, you can use logging as usual.

```
#sample.py
import logging

logging.info('This is a log message')
```

You can see more details [here](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/features/logcapture.feature). And also [here](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/403)